# How to specify how much disk I am using but for every folder I have

Tags: disk-usage

I have been informed that I am using a particular amount of disk on a shared computer.

When I log into it, and I do

```
du -hs
```

certainly I am using that amount.

My home directory has three directories with their subdirectories

What I would like to know is how much each of these directories use. Is there a command that can give me this info? or should I go to each one and do `du -hs`?

Comment: Use `du -sk dir1 dir2 dir3`. Read `man du`.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the "s"

```
du -h
```

will list all directories from the directory you do this and show a total for each directory recursively.

```
 du -h --max-depth=1
```

will only go 1 directory deep.

What you really want is this one:

```
 du -h | sort -h
```

will sort it from high to low.